# Test whether a subset of data is significantly different from a larger set of data

Tags: distributions, anova, t-test, modeling, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I would like to know the appropriate statistical test for the following data:

I have a dataset of distances in km (10,000 cases) which represent the distance between a motorway and a point of interest. 50 of these points of interest have been burgled. I want to know whether there is a significant effect of distance from motorway between points of interest that have been burgled and not burgled.

it looks as though there are more burgles closer to motorways but there are also more points of interest close to motorways so how do i disentangle this?

An issue I'm struggling to get my head around is that i want to compare a sample of 50 v 10000 therefore would a t test be appropriate?

Comment: I'm trying to get a sense of what your data looks like. For each point of interest do you only have two bits of information: 1) Distance from motorway; 2) Whether or not it's been burgled? If so, you may want to consider using a logistic regression to determine whether the probability of a point of interest being burgled varies as a function of its proximity to a motorway

Comment: Yes that is correct, distance in km and binary 1 0 of it has been burgled. Thank you, I will look into logistic regression. Would there be something more simple that I could also do to begin with?

Comment: You could divide the distances into groups (e.g., close to motorway, medium distance from motorway, long distance from motorway, etc.) and then use a one-way Chi-square test to see if the proportions of points of interests that are burgled varies between groups. Typically though, it's normally recommended that continuous variables (such as distance) are analysed as continuous variables, rather than trying to break them up into discrete (i.e., close, medium, far)

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Ian_Fin's first comment: this is a problem that can be solved well with a logistic regression. The fact that the distribution of distance to motorways is skewed should not be an issue.